# Why this code generate a link?

Tags: javascript, html, href

This code snap:

```html
<a href="javascript:window.prompt('Press OK button to insert this link in the new window ...', '<a href=javascript:window.close();> Close me 
            </a >')" target="new">
        Open "prompt" dialog
</a>
```

Open it in Chrome, click link `Open "prompt" dialog`, then click `OK`. It will generate a link in current web page. Why?

I see document of `prompt()`. It says `prompt()` returns a string which user inputs in, in this case: `<a href=javascript:window.close();> Close me </a >`.

I tried to replace `href` in the code to the return value of `prompt()`:

```html
<a href="'<a href=javascript:window.close();> Close me </a >'" target="new">
    Open "prompt" dialog
</a>
```

Then the link failed to open with error: *Your file was not found*.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: You can not put `<a>` tags inside the `href` of an `<a>` tag. Read all you can do with `<a>` tags here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: My question maybe a little confusing. I updated it to make it more clear. The `<a>` in `href` is not my problem.

Comment: To stress: this only appears to be working *in Chrome*. Firefox and Safari do not show the behaviour you're wondering about.

Comment: @deceze Firefox has the similar behavior, but not exactly the same. Firefox would open the prompt window in new tab. When click OK, a link will be generated in the new tab. The original web page remains unchanged. I don't have mac at my hand, not sure what will happen in Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `window.prompt()` or `target="new"`, it is due to `javascript:` protocol's behavior. I've made a simplified example below:

```
<span>content_ahead</span>
<a href="javascript:(function(){return 'result_content'})()">
  click_me
</a>
```

In the above example, when `click_me` is clicked, the page content will be wiped out and only display text `result_content`, no `content_ahead` span and no `click_me` link any more.

Explanation:

1. When `click_me` is clicked, browser will execute javascript program defined by `javascript:` protocol.
2. After the execution, if a String is returned, the browser will take it as the content of "new page" and "open" it. Anyway, it's the same logic as `href` to `http:` or `https://` -- fetch data and display it as new page. You can take this experiment in Firefox, where even the address bar is changed to `javascript://(function(){return 'result_content'})()`.
3. After the execution, if no String is return, there is no content for the "new page". Browser will keep displaying the old one.

For reference, here is an old [article](http://www.webreference.com/js/column35/protocol.html) describing the javascript statement in `javascript:` URL:

> The JavaScript statement used in a javascript: URL should not return any value. For example, the alert() method doesn't return a value; in other words, it returns undefined. If the statement returns undefined, the browser simply executes it. However, if it returns an explicit value, the browser loads a new page, with the javascript: URL in the Location bar, and the returned value in the body of the page.